# how to render partial on everything except a certain action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, partial, content-for

I have a _header.html.erb partial which is where I put my navbar

on my launch page I don't want to display the navbar.

this is the `body` of application.html.erb

```
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div id="container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
```

How do I render it on every action except specific actions on specific controllers?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Replace your render with this:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' unless @disable_nav %>
```

Then you can simply set `disable_nav` to true in any controller action you like:

```
def landing_page
  @disable_nav = true
end
```

---

As a `before_action`, which I'd encourage over the above:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def disable_nav
  @disable_nav = true
end
```

**my_controller**

```
before_action :disable_nav, only: [:landing_page]
```

Comment: You can also do `=render partial: "layouts/header" unless current_page?(landing_page_url)`

Comment: use before_action instead of before_filter with Rails > 4

Answer (score 7):

You can put that logic in your stylesheets, in your controller or in your views (this last one, only for whole controllers).

### Stylesheets

If you want to add the logic in your stylesheets, first add to your body tag the following classes:

```
<body class="<%= "#{controller.controller_name} #{controller.action_name}" %>">
```

Then, in your css, add something like this:

```
body.controller.action .navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

### Controller

To add this logic to your controller, add a before filter to your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :show_navbar

  protected
  def show_navbar
    @show_navbar = true
  end
end
```

Then, if you don't want to show the navbar in CarsController, do this:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :show_navbar, only: [list, of, actions]
end
```

where `[list, of, actions]` are the actions you don't want to show the navbar in.

Finally, change you layout to look like this:

```
<% if @show_navbar -%>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end -%
```

### Views

If you want to disable the header for whole controllers, first, move the header to `app/views/application/` and change your render to:

```
<%= render partial: 'header' %>
```

Finally, in those controllers without navbar, add an empty `_header.html.erb` to `app/views/controller_name`.

For this option to work, you need at least Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I would set a different layout for those specific actions on specific controllers.

Comment: Given that there is so much repetition (all but a header) I wouldn't consider it.

Comment: you can have a if condition around the header partial that would run every time by default except for the specific condition.

Comment: Then that's not a different layout.

Comment: ya its not a different layout if you consider having a condition to check whether to have header or not.