# Render parial on certain action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Probably a newbie question, but when my user visits job#index I want to show a partial that is stored in my views/layouts called _subnav.html.erb.

This only needs to render when the user is at jobs#index.

Can someone help me with this but also understand how it works.

Comment: Do you want to include the nav in a layout template? Is there a reason why `render partial: 'layouts/subnav'` within `jobs/index` will not suffice?

Comment: I tried that and it just puts the partial across the whole index, rather than where I need it. Basically I'm just trying to include the sub navbar under the navigation bar when the user is on jobs#index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [`content blocks`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for).

Within your layout file, such as layout/application.haml, place this code where you want the subnav to be rendered:

```
= content_for :subnav
```

..and within your view file (jobs/index.haml)

```
- content_for :subnav
    = render partial: 'layouts/subnav'
```

Couple of alternatives:

1. Check controller#action in layout file and only show for jobs#index
2. Add a simple @show_sub_nav instance variable and set to true within your controller. In your layout file: `= render partial: 'layouts/subnav' if @show_sub_nav`

You can see how to achieve (2) with [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395153/how-to-render-partial-on-everything-except-a-certain-action/13395938#13395938).